# Session timeout does not notice work being done in Unity web player and alerts the user. How can I prevent this?

Tags: session, timeout, unity-game-engine, ping, polling

Currently I have a web application with a session timeout window that pops up after 20 minutes of inactivity. However, I noticed that when I work inside and play inside the Unity web player, the session time out window appears after 20 minutes of working in Unity (in which it shouldn't pop up because working in Unity should not be considered inactivity).

I was wondering, how can I prevent this? How can I make a script in Unity that calls or does polling to web app notifying that activity is being done in Unity? What about implementing ping?

The web application is in ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: Disable the session timeout while you're developing?

Comment: This is a deployed web application. It's not part of developing. I just accessing unity web player.

Comment: Then what do you mean you are 'doing work in Unity?'  As in, playing in the webapp?

Comment: Not enough information. What system is driving the logout timer? If you can use Javascript to send a "heartbeat", [the Unity WebPlayer can call JS on the page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html).

Comment: so if I wanted Unity to pass the activity of mouse clicks on the scene in the web player, I would just create a mouse click function and then pass that function via javascript to the web app?